# How to save command in GIT

Tags: git

I know that GIT has command (`git ???`) to save some calls like 
`git log --oneline --decorate --graph`, and than call tham simplier, like `git nice-log`, but I can't find it :(

Comment: Git alias: https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Comment: @mparnisari thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this site](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log) does what you ask; you type `git config --global alias.lg "log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"` to add `git lg` as an alias for the pretty formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases)

```
git config --global alias.nice-log "log --graph --oneline --decorate=short"
```

Usage:

```
git nice-log
```

Note that you can even pass new flags to the command:

```
git nice-log --branches=* --remotes=*
```